# Django, annotate, order_by Сортировка по нескольким полям, лежащих в других моделях

Tags: python, django, сортировка, orm

Требуется отсортировать объекты, по полям в других моделях.

Основная модель <--(несколько объектов документов1(сортировка по полю дата))

Основная модель <--(несколько объектов документов2(сортировка по полю дата)).

Требуется выбрать максимальные даты в объектах документов1 и документов2, после этого выбрать максимальную дату между документов1 и документов2, и по ней произвести сортировку в наборе основных моделей

Пример:

```
new_docs_tasks.annotate(gs=Max('owner_process__request__requestdocument__doc__registered'), guag=Min('owner_process__request__gsrequestdata__gsdocument__doc__registered'))
```

В данном запросе выбрал макс даты для документов1(`gs`) и документов1(`guag`),как теперь выбрать максимальную дату между `gs` и `guag`, чтобы ее засунуть  `order_by`?
есть решение через `sort`, но приходится преобразовывать в `list`, работает не очень быстро, учитывая что его еще придется потом сложить с другим набором

Comment: Cхематично filter(gs__lte = Max('owner_process__request__requestdocument__doc__registered'), gs__gte > Min...).order_by("gs") Так разве не работает?